# System can't find path

Tags: java, file, path

Trying to practice Java by doing basic functionality like reading input.

I am trying to parse  `movies-sample.txt` found in:

```
C:\University\BigDataManagement\Data-Mining\hw1\src\main\resources\movies-sample.txt
```

Trying to reach `movies-sample.txt` from

```
C:\University\BigDataManagement\Data-Mining\hw1\src\main\java
   \univ\bigdata\course\MoviesReviewsQueryRunner.java
```

Using the answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868369/how-to-read-a-large-text-file-line-by-line-using-java) on how to parse a large file line by line.

```
File file = new File("../../../../../resources/movies-sample.txt");
```

I am getting the following error:

> The system cannot find the path specified

Given the above two paths, what am I doing incorrect?

Comment: The thing you are doing incorrect is that Java is not a scripting language, it doesn't run from where your `class` is located and it **certainly** doesn't run from where your source is located. Just use the full path.

Comment: Your home directory is not the path of your file but the folder where your src is located in. So it's C:\University\BigDataManagement\Data-Mining\hw1 (Disclaimer: That's not always true, your home may be different based on how you run your application!)

Comment: Oh I wasn't aware of that. Thanks for the enlightenment.

Comment: @Ben that should be the answer ;)

Comment: Is this file to be distributed with the app., in the Jar?

Comment: @Ben that depends on how you run the program, it's not generally true.

Comment: @BoristheSpider That's true, which is why I placed it as a comment over an answer to just quickly get the message through without creating (too much) confusion by exluding several other options ;)

Comment: Since you file is located in the resource folder (located in the src folder) the following should also work: ClassLoader cl = getClass().getClassLoader(); File f = new File(cl.getResource("movie-samples.txt").getFile());

Comment: If it's a web app then the `resources` folder is your root element, otherwise it will be `src` as mentioned. So you can access the file directly byits name: `new File("movies-sample.txt");`

Comment: @Flocke `File` doesn't work with opaque paths, and whilst your solution will work for running the code locally, it will break as soon as the code is packaged. That is what `ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream` is for.

Comment: @chŝdk again, this is not generally true. If people would stop using `File` for locations inside deployments it would make me a much happier person. It's not a `File`, it's a classloader resource. The two are far from the same.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Yes you are right, and as I said it will always depend on the situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a web app then the `resources` folder is your root element, otherwise it will be the `src` folder as mentioned in comments.

In your case here as you are writing a standalone Java program and as your file is loacted in the `resources` folder, you can use **[`CLassLoader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html)** to read the file as a stream.

This is how should be your code:

```
ClassLoader classloader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
InputStream is = classloader.getResourceAsStream("movies-sample.txt");
```

Then you will be able to read the `is` stream line by line.

Comment: Thanks for the help, using `BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));` I am finally able to process each line.

Comment: @TonyTannous Great, glad it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you run your program directly from command line, then the path must be related to your current directory.

If you run your program from an IDE, then the current directory of the runnin program depends on the IDE and the way it is configured.

You can determine what is the current directory with `System.getProperty("user.dir")`

Whatever, hard coding a path in an application is always a bad thing because you cannot ensure where the run was launched from. Either:

- it is a user resource, then its path must be input in some way (*open...* in GUIs apps)
- it is a resource needed by the app to run correctly and it should be embedded in some way into the app itself (look for Resource Bundle)
- it is a kind of *optional* external resource (config file for example, or path specified in a config file) and its location should be computed in some way.